# SDL Create window not creating window on Mac os X

Tags: c, sdl

I am following the [Lazy Foo tutorial](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php) on SDL.

When creating a window with `SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN` and running the binary the menu bar appears, but the window does not. Need some direction on what I can do to further debug this.

I've also tried to manually set window position with no luck.

```
SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                  SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                  SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", 100, 100, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

Everything compiles successfully and `SDL_GetError()` does not produce any errors. I logged to a file to confirm.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE *log_file;
    log_file = fopen("log.log", "a+");
    
    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    
    //The surface contained by the window
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;

    //Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 )
    {
        fprintf(log_file, "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                  SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        
        if (window == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(log_file, "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        }
        else
        {
            //Get window surface
            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

            //Fill the surface white
            SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF));
            
            //Update the surface
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            
             fprintf(log_file, "SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());

            //Wait two seconds
            SDL_Delay(2000);
        }
    }
    
    //Destroy window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    //Quit SDL subsystems
    SDL_Quit();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it work any better if you pump the event loop?

Comment: Is the `screenSurface` ok? (not `NULL` that is)

Comment: @genpfault pumping worked, I moved on to drawing a line and looking at the [documentation for SDL_RenderDrawLine](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawLine) they used `SDL_PollEvent()` in a `while` loop. I switched over to that. 

Now I am facing the problem of not seeing the lines that were drawn.

Comment: strange ... IIRC drawing on screen should work without the event loop.

Comment: @DanielJour: Maybe on old non-composited systems.  Been seeing questions of this type crop up periodically on SO, almost always on a composited windowing system like macOS or Windows' DWM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it was not working was because I did not have an event loop set up.

I the [documentation on how to draw a line](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawLine) and got an example there.

```
SDL_Event event;

while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
  if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
    done = SDL_TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on where in your original post you would insert these lines?